# Rails access DB data as variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well honestly saying I am not sure what the question Title should, so what I am trying to implement is, I have a roles table which has name of roles that can be assigned to a user like admin, owner, seller, purchaser.

Now what I want to do is when checking permissions or assigning roles, I need to get the id of the role by its name. Say I try to add the role admin (with id 1) to a user, which will be entered in my table user_roles, then it will be, `user_roles.create(user_id: some_users_id, role_id: 1)`,

> now instead of doing role_id: 1, I am trying to do something like
>   role_id: :admin.

Everything in the website depends on the roles and permissions, so I can afford to keep the same in some kind of session or globally.

I could have kept the roles in the model and created the enum from the same, but the roles are being read from the database as admin can add new roles.

I using Rails 5.

Comment: How the values for `role_id` will save in real time? Are you displaying a select box with all roles and picking the ids from there?

Comment: @Pavan There will be a dropdown while assigning, but what about when I will be checking someone's role. I just gave the example to keep it simple.

Comment: Assuming the datatype of `role_id` is integer, then you can't save the name of the roles as values of `role_id`. You might need to create a new column as @SatishakumarAwati suggested with Varchar as datatype to store the role names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very flexible and robust pattern for doing user roles is to use three tables:

```
class User << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  def has_role?(name, resource = nil)
    roles.where({ name: name, resource: resource }.compact).exists?
  end

  def add_role(name, resource = nil)
    role = Role.find_or_create_by({ name: name, resource: resource }.compact)
    user_roles.find_or_create_by(role: role)
  end
end

# rails g model role name:string:index resource:belongs_to:polymorpic 
class Role << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

# rails g model user_role user:belongs_to role:belongs_to 
# add a unique compound index on user_id and role_id.
class UserRole << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :role_id
end
```

The `role` table stores the normalized definition of a role. And the `user_roles` join table stores the applied roles.

Why?

- Users can have an unlimited amount / combination of roles.
- Using a normalized table for roles avoids duplication. Your not duplicating the string "admin" for every role applied to a user.
- Roles can optionally be scoped to a resource.
- Roles can be added / revoked without modifying the user record.
- Roles can even be created at runtime if needed. As in role definitions can be added via a GUI if you for example where building the next Drupal.

Try out [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Using redis/memcached or storing the roles in the session are not very robust solutions. Since authorization is a key part of the application you'll want the  fault tolerance that a rbdms gives you. You can however use this in combination with model level caching to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

As far my understanding, you need a variable to store the data in below format.

```
{'admin' => 1, 'owner' => '2', 'seller' => '3', 'customer' => '4'}
```

Two ways it can be achieved.1.Rails Cache , 2. Redis.

During rails server start collect all **role name** and **id** pairs for each role from **roles** table and store into rails cache/redis. In both cases **key** will be **role name** and **value** will be **role id**.

Whenever user adds new role make sure to update same in rails cache/redis stores.

and similarly handle roles delete, here you need to delete keys from rails cache/redis.

I recommend using Redis store, it can be used keep single copy of data across multiple rails servers.

Answer (score 0):

And in case you don't have caching server, simply create a `role_mapping.rb` file in your `initializers` folder where,

```
ROLES = Role.select([:id, :name]).as_json.map{ |h| h.values.reverse }.to_h
```

In your controller,

```
user_roles.create(user_id: some_users_id, role_id: ROLES[params[:role]])
```

Hope it helps..

---

When new roles are created, in your `Role` model,

```
after_create :update_roles_mapping

def update_roles_mapping
  Constant.const_set('ROLES', Role.select([:id, :name]).as_json.map{ |h| h.values.reverse }.to_h)
end
```